# 2 Intent Filters, 1 Activity - Which opened it?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Is there a way to know which Intent Filter is responsible for launching an Activity which has two Intent Filters defined in AndroidManifest.xml? I want a slightly different set of logic, but not enough that should require a whole new Activity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, found it. Just wasn't looking hard enough...

Using `this.getIntent().getAction()` in your Activity will spit out exactly what I was looking for, a String to identify which Intent Filter Action opened it.

Comment: You can see how this is done in the contacts application here: http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#J8HqCFe1rOo/src/com/android/contacts/ContactsListActivity.java&q=contacts%20git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/packages%20package:%22git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git%22&d=0&l=437